# Turn a pylint warning as an error under Eclipse/pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

I'm working with pylint under Eclipse for my python code.
I have some warnings given by pylint that I want to be marked as errors.

Graphically it consists in a red cross instead of a yellow warning panel.

Any idea ?

PS : The warning I want more severe is W0102, ie dangerous-default-value

Answer (score 0):

In PyDev you can choose the severity of each of the message types in PyLint (i.e.: Fatal, Errors, Warnings, Conventions, Refactor) -- you can do that in the PyLint preferences page inside PyDev, but there's nothing related to changing the message type of a single item into an error.

I.e.: if you need to change the message type of some message from the Warning message type to the Error message type, PyLint itself should support that (and if/when it does, you should configure the parameters to pass to PyLint in the preferences page).